# Compartilhar arquivo de Áudio

Tags: android

Gravei um arquivo de áudio, tipo .3gp, pelo microfone do celular, na minha própria aplicação 'Android'.

Gostaria de saber como compartilhar via Intent, pois só compartilho textos.

Obs: tenho o endereço do arquivo e tudo mais. Preciso somente da função de compartilhar arquivo, seja áudio ou vídeo!

Answer (score 2):

**Com o path do dispositivo você pode utilizar:**

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("audio/3gpp");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_sound)));
```

> Opção de função para whatsapp, por exemplo:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    String audioClipFileName="audio.3gp";
                    shareIntent.setType("audio/3gpp");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+"/sdcard/"+audioClipFileName));
                    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Compartilhando no whatsapp"));
                }
```

> CASO SEU PATH SEJA EXTERNO. Lembrando as pastas MeuApp/Imagens deve ser criados na instalação do app:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/MeuApp/Imagens/";
```

[Para mais detalhes, clique aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48196/salvamento-de-dados-em-android?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: O arquivo esta na pasta 'data/data/aplicacao/files/pasta/arquivo.3gp'.  Como eu coloco nessa Uri? Lollipop

Comment: ATUALIZADO!......