# Android salvar a imagem de perfil do usuário

Tags: android, imagem, login

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida qual é o melhor método de salvar a imagem de perfil do usuário do app que estou desenvolvendo, onde na tela de login vai carregar a imagem do perfil do usuário e tela inicial também. Pelas pesquisas que fiz tem 2 formas:

1ª) Salvar a imagem no banco de dados.

2ª) Salvar a imagem em uma pasta interna do app e no banco de dados salvar o caminho dessa imagem.

Alguém sabe qual é a melhor forma ou seja que consome menos recursos de processamento. E no caso de salvar em uma pasta interna como eu posso fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nenhuma das duas formas vai causar problemas de processamento. Você está trabalhando com leitura de dados. Isso é ordens de magnitude mais lento do que qualquer coisa que o processador possa estar fazendo. Processador é o menor dos seus problemas.

Dado que estamos falando de um arquivo binário, para mim faz mais sentido salvar na pasta da sua aplicação. Presumindo que sua aplicação só permite um login de cada vez, você não precisa nem de salvar o caminho da foto em um banco de dados-- um caminho fixo resolve isso (pense algo como /dadosdaminhaaplicacao/perfil.jpg).

Quanto a como fazer isso, acho que já tem uma resposta bastante completa aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48228/26404

Para qualquer dúvida não respondida lá ou em outra pergunta, fique à vontade para abrir uma nova.

Comment: Pablo, obrigado pelo resposta e concordo com você que seria melhor salvar em uma pasta, mas como esqueci de mencionar na pergunta o app que só vai permitir ter um usuário por dispositivo ele vai ter uma versão desktop onde o usuário vai poder ter seu usuário no android e no PC. Nesse caso como eu faria para que esta foto seja salva no servidor para que o app desktop baixe essa imagem?

Comment: Não sei se é uma má ideia, mas nesse caso se eu fizesse uma classe com os métodos responsáveis por sincronizar as mudanças com servidor em nuvem. Aí por exemplo eu faria uma tabela no banco de dados que armazenaria todas as mudanças que o usuário fez e em segundo plano o app verificaria se está autenticado com o servidor, caso esteja ele verificaria se a tabela tem um registro se tivesse ele executava o método da classe de sincronização de acordo com o tipo de mudança registrada no banco e depois apagaria esse registro do banco será que é a melhor forma ou tem um jeito mais simples?

Comment: Nesse caso eu teria que fazer o app ficar acessado constantemente o servidor caso tenha alguma mudança ele sincronizaria, mas como eu faria ele ficar acessando constantemente o servidor?, pq pode haver o caso do usuário ficar offline (sem internet) e depois voltar online.

Comment: Olá, @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante. Suas dúvidas parecem fugir do escopo dessa pergunta. Comentários aqui no Stack Overflow servem para esclarecimentos, não para novas perguntas. Se você publicar sua dúvida em uma nova pergunta, mais pessoas podem ser ajudadas, já que comentários não saem na busca.

Comment: Sim @Pablo vc esta certo essas dúvidas fogem da pergunta do post vou fazer outro post para essas dúvidas e encerrar esse.