# Como fazer download de um banco de dados e inseri-lo no app?

Tags: android

O app baixa o banco de dados de acordo com o estado do usuário e insere no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Nâo se faz isso. A pasta de *assets* é para recursos estáticos, disponíveis durante a construção do aplicativo. Você deve salvar dados personalizados ou dinâmicos no dispositivo, e não no APK.

Dependendo do que você pretende fazer, há diferentes abordagens preferenciais. Dê uma olhada no [guia oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html?hl=pt-br) para decidir o melhor para seu caso.

Comment: A intenção é fazer download de um arquivo de banco de dados para o armazenamento interno ou externo. Como faz? E como tenho acesso? Qual o caminho? Exemplo: /sdcard0/

Comment: Deu uma olhada no link? Além disso, veja essa resposta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48228/26404), que tem alguns exemplos.

Comment: A explicação é apenas como acessar um arquivo armazenado no armazenamento. A minha maior duvida é como fazer download de um banco de dados armazenado em um site. E inserir o banco no app.