# Criar/Editar arquivo (txt) em Android

Tags: java, android, arquivo

Olá... desculpe se postei no lugar errado ou de forma errada, pois sou novo no fórum (apesar de sempre lê-lo).

Lollipop me ajudou muito com a explicação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48228/68502

Porem tenho 3 dúvidas:

1. Se eu quiser manter os dados que contem no arquivo criado "MyFile"
   adicionando ou apagando o conteúdo, ou seja, para que mesmo que
   feche-se o App, ao abri-lo novamente possa recuperar e continuar editando      mantendo os
   dados,e se quizer limpar o conteudo arquivo "MyFile" dá pra fazer?
2. Se eu quiser somente criar o arquivo sem conteudo, somente preciso
   retirar as linhas de cód.:

   ```
   ... 
   String content = "Olá todos?"; //retirar
   ... 
   outputStream.write(content.getBytes()); //retirar
   ...
   ```
3. Posso criar o diretório e os arquivos em brancos (sem conteúdo) na
   raiz do projeto de forma que não preciso criar ao rodar o App visto que somente utilizarei eles?

---

Editado abaixo!

**Por favor estou travado nessa parte alguém... help-me!!!**

[image: Estrutura do Projeto:]

MainActivity.java

```js
package br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import static android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory;
import static br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria.R.id.btNovoBalanco;
import static br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria.R.id.nomeAuditor;
import static br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria.R.id.nomeFilial;
import static br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria.R.string.local;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public final SimpleDateFormat data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    public final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


    public EditText editTextBuscar;
    public TextView textViewBipados;
    public TextView textViewUltimosItens;
    public TextView textViewLocal;
    public TextView textViewAuditor;
    public TextView textViewTotal;
    public TextView textViewData;

    public Button btnRecomecar;
    public Button btnNovoBalanco;
    public Button btnFinalizar;
    String fileData = "data.txt";
    // String fileAuditor = "auditor.txt";
    // String fileBalanco = "balanco.txt";
    // String fileLocal = "local.txt";


    View popup1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
        textViewTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTotal);
        textViewAuditor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAuditor);
        textViewLocal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLocal);
        editTextBuscar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBuscar);
        textViewUltimosItens = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUltimosItens);
        textViewBipados = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBipados);

        btnNovoBalanco = (Button) findViewById(btNovoBalanco);
        btnFinalizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinalizar);
        btnRecomecar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecomecar);

        btnNovoBalanco.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openPopupStart(v);
                lerData();
            }
        });

        btnRecomecar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lerData();
            }
        });

    }

    public void lerData() {
        @SuppressWarnings("MismatchedQueryAndUpdateOfCollection")
        ArrayList<String> dataTXT;
        String dataConteudo = "";


        try {


            FileReader dataOut2 = new FileReader((fileData));
            BufferedReader dataLer = new BufferedReader(dataOut2);
            dataTXT = new ArrayList<>();
            while (dataLer.readLine() != null) {
                dataTXT.add(dataConteudo);
                textViewData.setText(dataConteudo);
                dataOut2.close();
            }

        }catch( Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }






    public void criarDataTXT(){
        String data = c.getTime().toString();
        //String auditor = textViewAuditor.getText().toString();
        // String local = textViewLocal.getText().toString();
        // String balanco = "";

        File path = new File(getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "files");
        File fileTXT = new File(path,fileData);


            try {

                FileWriter dataOut = new FileWriter(fileTXT);
                BufferedWriter dataPrint = new BufferedWriter(dataOut);
                dataPrint.write(data);
                dataPrint.flush();
                dataOut.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



    public void criarBalanco(){

        criarDataTXT();

    }

    public void openPopupStart(final View start) {

        this.popup1 = start;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_start, null);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Iniciar processo de balanço");
        alert.setView(promptView);

        final EditText input = (EditText) promptView.findViewById( nomeFilial);
        final EditText inputAuditor = (EditText) promptView.findViewById( nomeAuditor);

        input.requestFocus();
        input.setHint( local);
        input.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


        alert.setPositiveButton( R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String nomeFilial = input.getText().toString();
                String nomeAuditor = inputAuditor.getText().toString();

//                textViewLocal.setText( nomeFilial );
//                textViewData.setText( data.format( c.getTime() ) );
//                textViewAuditor.setText( nomeAuditor );

                try {
                    if (nomeFilial.equals( "" ) || nomeAuditor.equals( "" )) {
                        input.setError( getString( R.string.localVazio ) );
                        inputAuditor.setError( getString( R.string.auditorVazio ) );
                        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                "Digite o Local e Auditor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                        openPopupStart( null );
                    } else {
                        criarBalanco();
                        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                "Novo Balanço Criado!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        } ).setNegativeButton( "Cancelar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                "Novo Balanço cancelado!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    }
                } );


        // create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog popup = alert.create();

        popup.show();

    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_popup"
    tools:context="br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewLocal"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textViewLocal"
        android:background="@drawable/borda3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:labelFor="@+id/activity_main"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_00_00_0000"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLocal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borda3"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:labelFor="@+id/activity_main"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"

        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/local"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAuditor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLocal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borda3"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:labelFor="@+id/activity_main"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"

        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/auditor"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTotal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewAuditor"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewAuditor"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewAuditor"
        android:background="@drawable/borda2"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:labelFor="@+id/activity_main"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_0"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBipados"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewUltimosItens"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borda3"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:foregroundGravity="left"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:labelFor="@+id/activity_main"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewUltimosItens"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextBuscar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borda3"

        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/itens"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:labelFor="@+id/activity_main"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="   Itens Bipados"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextBuscar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAuditor"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borda"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leitor"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:hint="   Use o leitor..."
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:labelFor="@+id/activity_main"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,LabelFor,RtlHardcoded" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewBipados"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewBipados"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRecomecar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:text="@string/recomecar"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btNovoBalanco"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.77"
            android:onClick="openPopupStart"
            android:text="@string/novo_balanco"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFinalizar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/finalizar"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name="br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria.Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="br.com.aime.aimeappauditoria.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Cara, você pode fazer qualquer coisa dentro da lógica. Se faz sentido para você, tem como criar, apagar, refazer, enviar, bla bla bla, vários tipos de arquivos e diretórios. O que tem que tomar cuidado é na criação de um arquivo que pode ser editado, pois dependendo a situação, pode comprometer sua aplicação.

Comment: Por exemplo, você cria um txt que pode ser acessado com outro aplicativo e apagado, porém sua aplicação depende daquele conteúdo. Isso vai fazer com que seu app pare de funcionar, ou algo parecido.

Comment: Então isso eu consegui entender porém penso em criar usando o MODE PRIAVATE em um diretório específico, que penso eu somente pode-se acessar o arquivo pela aplicação, também acredito que de pra compartilhar permições  por ID, porém não estou muito preocupado com isso.. e sim em como fase-lo tem alguma dica? Em relação a lógica mesmo pois todos exemplos que visualizei..eles explicam como criar um novo e não editar o arquivo já existente... que foi criado no caso de não existir, ocorrido em outra execução da aplicação. Agradeço a atenção!