# Porque os arquivos do app permanecem após a desinstalação?

Tags: android

Estava lendo sobre armazenamento no Android, percebi que há o interno do app (/data/data/package/files) e o externo (que precisa de permissão).

No externo, temos o modo público e o privado (Android/data/package/files).
No privado, do armazenamento externo, ao desinstalar o app tudo aquilo é apagado, mas no interno não é(como é dito nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48196/salvamento-de-dados-em-android)). Porquê?

Isso não pode ficar comendo espaço extra do armazenamento do Android?
Em que casos usar um ou outro? E caso o usuário queira ele pode forçar esses arquivos a serem apagados?

Comment: Acho que para eventual reinstalação ele conseguir resgatar as preferências do usuário...

Comment: Creio que é justamente por uma questão de backup, pense assim, o autor quer remover o app por estar falhando ou por ter instalado de uma outra fonte, então ele vai instalar de uma fonte nova ou tentar reinstalar para corrigir, imagine se ele perdesse os dados todos, seria irritante, não? O proprio android creio que também tem sistema de backup, então mesmo que remova do aparelho talvez seja possivel restaurar depois.

Comment: Então nesse caso é recomendável colocar no interno apenas arquivos que você deseja que permaneçam após a reinstalação, certo? arquivos de preferências e coisas do tipo, eu não sabia disso e acabei fazendo um sistema de backup pro banco de dados do meu app, vou ver se passo pra memória interna do app mesmo

Comment: Onde você leu que no interno os arquivos não são apagados ao desinstalar o app?

Comment: @ramaral, na primeira resposta dessa pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48196/salvamento-de-dados-em-android, e também no meu app eu tinha uma foto salva no interno e quando eu limpava os dados do app ela continuava lá (agora estou testando novamente, mas não está mais pegando a foto ao limpar os dados/desinstalar, não sei se ela está sendo excluída mesmo ou o app ainda não rodou o método getImg())

Comment: O que é dito nessa resposta está errado.

Comment: @ramaral, foi erro de tradução, percebi agora na fonte que ele indicou que o texto diz exatamente o contrário, erro na tradução de uma palavra que prejudicou todo o texto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julgo que não leu bem a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) porque, ao contrário do que você diz, os arquivos guardados no [armazenamento interno](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) são apagados após a desinstalação do app.

O mesmo acontece no [armazenamento externo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles) se usar um directório de armazenamento privado chamando [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

Se pretende que os arquivos sobrevivam ao desinstalar do app deve gravá-los no armazenamento externo usando [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) para  obter um directório publico.

Comment: Realmente, eu testei no meu app e a imagem que estava no interno foi excluída após desinstalar, jurava que tinha visto que os arquivos permaneciam, aí após aquela resposta que mandei nos comentários achei que fosse uma certeza.